# Error while Installing SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I am facing the problem while installing SQL Server 2012 on my Lenovo ThinkPad. The same was working till now. However it seems, registry has been deleted. So I try to re-install same. But have no luck.

Kindly advise for the same.

Thanks a lot.

```
=== Verbose logging started: 25-06-2014  13:36:21  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7601.00  Calling process: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2012\x64\ScenarioEngine.exe ===
MSI (c) (E8:18) [13:36:21:173]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (E8:18) [13:36:21:173]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (E8:18) [13:36:21:173]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: D:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup\vs_setup.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (E8:18) [13:36:21:174]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (E8:18) [13:36:21:174]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (E8:18) [13:36:21:175]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (E8:18) [13:36:21:175]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (E8:18) [13:36:21:175]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:36:21:180]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction D:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup\vs_setup.msi
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:36:21:180]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:21:181]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:21:181]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:21:181]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: D:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup\vs_setup.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:428]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:457]: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:460]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer 3: 2 
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:466]: File will have security applied from OpCode.
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:470]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'D:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup\vs_setup.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:470]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: D:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup\vs_setup.msi has a digital signature
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:502]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: D:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup\vs_setup.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:502]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:502]: Original package ==> D:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup\vs_setup.msi
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:502]: Package we're running from ==> C:\Windows\Installer\4a2598.msi
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:524]: APPCOMPAT: Compatibility mode property overrides found.
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:524]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{D64B6984-242F-32BC-B008-752806E5FC44}'.
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:524]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:525]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:528]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:24:528]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:27:395]: File will have security applied from OpCode.
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:27:465]: Original patch ==> D:\redist\VisualStudioShell\KB2251489.msp
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:27:465]: Patch we're running from ==> C:\Windows\Installer\4a2599.msp
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:27:477]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying patch --> 'D:\redist\VisualStudioShell\KB2251489.msp' against software restriction policy
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:27:477]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: D:\redist\VisualStudioShell\KB2251489.msp has a digital signature
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:27:591]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: D:\redist\VisualStudioShell\KB2251489.msp is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:37:597]: File will have security applied from OpCode.
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:57:507]: Original patch ==> D:\redist\VisualStudioShell\VS10sp1-KB983509.msp
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:57:507]: Patch we're running from ==> C:\Windows\Installer\4a259a.msp
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:57:510]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying patch --> 'D:\redist\VisualStudioShell\VS10sp1-KB983509.msp' against software restriction policy
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:57:510]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: D:\redist\VisualStudioShell\VS10sp1-KB983509.msp has a digital signature
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:36:58:092]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: D:\redist\VisualStudioShell\VS10sp1-KB983509.msp is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:37:08:105]: File will have security applied from OpCode.
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:49:08:508]: Note: 1: 1305 2: D:\redist\VisualStudioShell\VS10sp1-KB983509-Pro.msp 3: 23 
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:50:48:063]: Note: 1: 1305 2: D:\redist\VisualStudioShell\VS10sp1-KB983509-Pro.msp 3: 23 
The system cannot read from the specified device.
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:51:09:086]: Note: 1: 1305 2: D:\redist\VisualStudioShell\VS10sp1-KB983509-Pro.msp 3: 23 
The system cannot read from the specified device.
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:868]: I/O on thread 10364 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:868]: I/O on thread 10928 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:868]: I/O on thread 6848 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:869]: I/O on thread 5332 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:869]: I/O on thread 7760 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:869]: I/O on thread 5856 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:51:11:871]: Unable to create a temp copy of patch 'D:\redist\VisualStudioShell\VS10sp1-KB983509-Pro.msp'.
The system cannot read from the specified device.
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:51:11:871]: Product: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU - Update '{F606AC5F-4A30-3D7F-BC43-1200864BD9E5}' could not be installed. Error code 1635. Additional information is available in the log file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20140625_132656\VSShell_Cpu32_1.log.

MSI (s) (34:50) [13:51:11:872]: Windows Installer installed an update. Product Name: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU. Product Version: 10.0.30319. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Update Name: {F606AC5F-4A30-3D7F-BC43-1200864BD9E5}. Installation success or error status: 1635.

MSI (s) (34:50) [13:51:11:873]: Product: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU - Update '{FC8EA2A2-65A3-366E-A687-5B63943A800F}' could not be installed. Error code 1635. Additional information is available in the log file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20140625_132656\VSShell_Cpu32_1.log.

MSI (s) (34:50) [13:51:11:873]: Windows Installer installed an update. Product Name: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU. Product Version: 10.0.30319. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Update Name: {FC8EA2A2-65A3-366E-A687-5B63943A800F}. Installation success or error status: 1635.

MSI (s) (34:50) [13:51:11:873]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:51:11:874]: Product: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (34:50) [13:51:11:874]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU. Product Version: 10.0.30319. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1635.

MSI (s) (34:50) [13:51:11:880]: Attempting to delete file C:\Windows\Installer\4a2599.msp
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:51:11:882]: Attempting to delete file C:\Windows\Installer\4a259a.msp
MSI (s) (34:50) [13:51:11:899]: MainEngineThread is returning 1635
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:899]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
This update package could not be opened. Verify that the update package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer update package.
D:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup\vs_setup.msi
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:900]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:900]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:900]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:900]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:900]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:901]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress 3: 2 
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:901]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress 3: 2 
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:901]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (34:D0) [13:51:11:901]: Restoring environment variables
MSI (c) (E8:18) [13:51:11:903]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (E8:18) [13:51:11:905]: MainEngineThread is returning 1635
=== Verbose logging stopped: 25-06-2014  13:51:11 ===
```

Comment: D: is CD drive for SQL 2012 set up

Comment: It seems as though setup simply can't retrieve the following file: 'D:\redist\VisualStudioShell\VS10sp1-KB983509-Pro.msp'.  Are you sure that exists?  Do this (PowerShell): `Test-Path "D:\redist\VisualStudioShell\VS10sp1-KB983509-Pro.msp"`.  What does that return?  If `True`, then verify the security context that you're running setup.exe under has permissions to also access those files.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. File Exists in the DVD. I tried to run the same but Windows Installer error message appears as "The update patch cannot be installed by Windows Installer  because  program to be updated may be missing or Update patch may update the diffrent version of the program.

Comment: I have uninstalled Visual Studio 2010 , therefore said service pack cannot be applied